# Hide everything between 2 h2 tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html snippet;

```
<h2>Headline 1</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum bla bla</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum bla bla</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum bla bla</p>

<h2>Headline 2</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum bla bla</p>

<h2>Headline 3</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum bla bla</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum bla bla</p>
```

I wish to somehow, via jquery, target each "block" so i can append a div arround it. By "block" i mean all the code between h2 start-tag and down to the last p-tag, before the next h2 start-tag. The last h2-tag within the section, should just take the last p-tag.

Any suggestions as to how i best do this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863356/jquery-how-to-select-from-here-until-the-next-h2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('h2').each(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('h2').add(this).wrapAll('<div class="foo">');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RUKDj/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.nextUntil` if you just want to hide all elements between two `h2`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/qNWJ6/1/)

```
$('h2').nextUntil('h2').hide();
```

If you want to block anywhere b/w 2 `h2` then you can use,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/qNWJ6/2/)

```
$('h2').each (function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('h2').wrapAll('<div class="hidden">');
});
```