# Want to wrap all elements in one div from <h2> next Until another <h2>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm having a small problem wrapping my `HTML` using `jQuery` from one `<h2>` tag to another `<h2>`

This is quite similar to this, but the solution is not the same. [jQuery: How to select "from here until the next H2"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863356/jquery-how-to-select-from-here-until-the-next-h2)

My problem is, that I want to wrap these elements as a whole.

Here is my `HTML` as an example.

```
<div class="info-hold">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi dolore quae, quas ipsum illo magni vero quaerat quam ipsam iste autem quisquam, aperiam laudantium cumque, porro amet! Sint ipsa, laborum!</p>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ab officiis nostrum modi aliquam, rem dicta deleniti provident sunt, libero nobis ea adipisci praesentium dolore fuga nesciunt iure at maiores!</p>
    <h2>Lorem 2</h2>
    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi dolore quae, quas ipsum illo magni vero quaerat quam ipsam iste autem quisquam, aperiam laudantium cumque, porro amet! Sint ipsa, laborum!</p>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ab officiis nostrum modi aliquam, rem dicta deleniti provident sunt, libero nobis ea adipisci praesentium dolore fuga nesciunt iure at maiores!</p>
    <h2>Lorem 3</h2>
    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi dolore quae, quas ipsum illo magni vero quaerat quam ipsam iste autem quisquam, aperiam laudantium cumque, porro amet! Sint ipsa, laborum!</p>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ab officiis nostrum modi aliquam, rem dicta deleniti provident sunt, libero nobis ea adipisci praesentium dolore fuga nesciunt iure at maiores!</p>
</div>
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
<div class="info-hold">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <div class="info-wrapper">
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi dolore quae, quas ipsum illo magni vero quaerat quam ipsam iste autem quisquam, aperiam laudantium cumque, porro amet! Sint ipsa, laborum!</p>
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ab officiis nostrum modi aliquam, rem dicta deleniti provident sunt, libero nobis ea adipisci praesentium dolore fuga nesciunt iure at maiores!</p>
    </div>
    <h2>Lorem 2</h2>
    <div class="info-wrapper">
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi dolore quae, quas ipsum illo magni vero quaerat quam ipsam iste autem quisquam, aperiam laudantium cumque, porro amet! Sint ipsa, laborum!</p>
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ab officiis nostrum modi aliquam, rem dicta deleniti provident sunt, libero nobis ea adipisci praesentium dolore fuga nesciunt iure at maiores!</p>
    </div>
    <h2>Lorem 3</h2>
    <div class="info-wrapper">
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi dolore quae, quas ipsum illo magni vero quaerat quam ipsam iste autem quisquam, aperiam laudantium cumque, porro amet! Sint ipsa, laborum!</p>
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ab officiis nostrum modi aliquam, rem dicta deleniti provident sunt, libero nobis ea adipisci praesentium dolore fuga nesciunt iure at maiores!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The html is there and I cannot modify it, I need a jQuery solution for this.

**Thanks.**

This is not a duplicate, since the problem is different!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: How to select "from here until the next H2"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863356/jquery-how-to-select-from-here-until-the-next-h2)

Comment: Do you even read my description?

Comment: The problem may be slightly different, but the other answer points you in the direction to solve both.

Comment: in your final project, can we said you need to wrap "p" + "ul" + "p" ?

Comment: yes, wrap all that is in between (all next elements) from one h2 to another into a single div element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `nextUtil` then `wrapAll`

```js
$('h2').each(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil('h2').wrapAll($('<div>', { class:'info-wrapper' }))
})
```

```css
.info-wrapper{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="info-hold">
  <h2>Lorem</h2>
  <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi dolore quae, quas ipsum illo magni vero quaerat quam ipsam iste autem quisquam, aperiam laudantium cumque, porro amet! Sint ipsa, laborum!</p>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ab officiis nostrum modi aliquam, rem dicta deleniti provident sunt, libero nobis ea adipisci praesentium dolore fuga nesciunt iure at maiores!</p>
  <h2>Lorem 2</h2>
  <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi dolore quae, quas ipsum illo magni vero quaerat quam ipsam iste autem quisquam, aperiam laudantium cumque, porro amet! Sint ipsa, laborum!</p>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ab officiis nostrum modi aliquam, rem dicta deleniti provident sunt, libero nobis ea adipisci praesentium dolore fuga nesciunt iure at maiores!</p>
  <h2>Lorem 3</h2>
  <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi dolore quae, quas ipsum illo magni vero quaerat quam ipsam iste autem quisquam, aperiam laudantium cumque, porro amet! Sint ipsa, laborum!</p>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ab officiis nostrum modi aliquam, rem dicta deleniti provident sunt, libero nobis ea adipisci praesentium dolore fuga nesciunt iure at maiores!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this one, looks more elegant!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this following code : 
Loop over every h2, find the next three element, wrap them all.

```
$.each($(".info-hold").find("h2"), function() {

    $(this).nextAll().slice(0, 3).wrapAll('<div class="info-wrapper">');

})
```

[Live Demo JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rzpjo97k/)

Comment: Thanks, I was mising slice(0,3) in my code... I was wrapping every element and didnt know how to fix it!

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer, I thought – if only for completion – that I'd take a moment and offer a way to achieve your requirements using only plain JavaScript, albeit using mostly ES6, which requires up-to-date browsers:

```
function wrapAll(opts) {
  // setting the defaults for the function:
  var settings = {
    // the element-node from which to begin wrapping:
    'wrapFrom': null,

    // a CSS selector to define the element before
    // which wrapping should stop:
    'wrapTo': null,

    // the element-type to wrap with:
    'wrapWith': 'div',

    // the class - if any - to apply to the
    // wrapping element:
    'wrapClass': 'wrapper'
  };

  // using Object.keys() to iterate over the
  // opts Object (or an empty object-literal)
  // if no opts Object is supplied:
  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(function(key) {

    // updating the default settings with
    // the value held in the opts Object:
    settings[key] = opts[key];
  });

  // if there is no settings.wrapFrom node, or
  // no settings.wrapTo string:
  if (!settings.wrapFrom || !settings.wrapTo) {

    // we quit here:
    return false;
  }

  // creating the element with which we can wrap:
  var wrapper = document.createElement(settings.wrapWith),

    // creating an Array-literal for later use:
    classes = [];

  // if the settigns.wrapClass value is a string:
  if ('string' === typeof settings.wrapClass) {

    // we set classes to the value of the String,
    // after splitting it into an Array, using
    // String.prototype.split() and a regular
    // expression, by breaking it apart 
    // on sequences of one or more (+)
    // white-space characters (\s):
    classes = settings.wrapClass.split(/\s+/);

  // otherwise, if settings.wrapClass is an Array:
  } else if (settings.wrapClass instanceof Array) {

    // we pass the existing array to the
    // classes variable:
    classes = settings.wrapClass;
  }

  // here we iterate over the classes, using
  // Array.prototype.forEach():
  classes.forEach(function(cN) {
    // cN, the first argument, is a reference
    // to the current array-element (the class-name)
    // of the Array over which we're iterating.

    // here we use the Element.classList API to
    // add the class-name to the wrapper element,
    // after trimming away leading and trailing
    // white-space, using String.prototype.trim():
    wrapper.classList.add(cN.trim());
  });

  // here we navigate from the settings.wrapFrom
  // node to its parentNode, and insert the wrapper
  // Element before the next-sibling of the
  // settings.wrapFrom node:
  settings.wrapFrom.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, settings.wrapFrom.nextSibling);

  // while there is a next-sibling of the wrapper,
  // and either that next-sibling is not an element
  // (which has a nodeType of 1), or the next-sibling
  // is an element node and that element node does not
  // match the selector supplied in settings.wrapTo:
  while (wrapper.nextSibling && (wrapper.nextSibling.nodeType !== 1 || (wrapper.nextSibling.nodeType === 1 && !wrapper.nextSibling.matches(settings.wrapTo)))) {

    // we append the next-sibling to the
    // wrapper:
    wrapper.appendChild(wrapper.nextSibling);
  }

}

// here we retrieve an HTMLCollection using document.querySelectorAll,
// and convert that array-like HTMLCollection into an Array using
// Array.from; then using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over
// the Array of nodes, which then calls the wrapAll function:
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('h2')).forEach(function(heading) {
  wrapAll({
    'wrapFrom': heading,
    'wrapTo': 'h2',
    'wrapClass': 'info-wrapper'
  });
});
```

```js
function wrapAll(opts) {
  var settings = {
    'wrapFrom': null,
    'wrapTo': null,
    'wrapWith': 'div',
    'wrapClass': 'wrapper'
  };

  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(function(key) {
    settings[key] = opts[key];
  });

  if (!settings.wrapFrom || !settings.wrapTo) {
    return false;
  }

  var wrapper = document.createElement(settings.wrapWith),
    collection = [],
    classes = [];

  if ('string' === typeof settings.wrapClass) {
    classes = settings.wrapClass.split(/\s+/);
  } else if (settings.wrapClass instanceof Array) {
    classes = settings.wrapClass;
  }

  classes.forEach(function(cN) {
    wrapper.classList.add(cN.trim());
  });

  settings.wrapFrom.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, settings.wrapFrom.nextSibling);

  while (wrapper.nextSibling && (wrapper.nextSibling.nodeType !== 1 || (wrapper.nextSibling.nodeType === 1 && !wrapper.nextSibling.matches(settings.wrapTo)))) {
    wrapper.appendChild(wrapper.nextSibling);
  }

}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('h2')).forEach(function(heading) {
  wrapAll({
    'wrapFrom': heading,
    'wrapTo': 'h2',
    'wrapClass': 'info-wrapper'
  });
});
```

```css
.info-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-hold">
  <h2>Lorem</h2>
  <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi dolore quae, quas ipsum illo magni vero quaerat quam ipsam iste autem quisquam, aperiam laudantium cumque, porro amet! Sint ipsa, laborum!</p>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ab officiis nostrum modi aliquam, rem dicta deleniti provident sunt, libero nobis ea adipisci praesentium dolore fuga nesciunt iure at maiores!</p>
  <h2>Lorem 2</h2>
  <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi dolore quae, quas ipsum illo magni vero quaerat quam ipsam iste autem quisquam, aperiam laudantium cumque, porro amet! Sint ipsa, laborum!</p>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ab officiis nostrum modi aliquam, rem dicta deleniti provident sunt, libero nobis ea adipisci praesentium dolore fuga nesciunt iure at maiores!</p>
  <h2>Lorem 3</h2>
  <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi dolore quae, quas ipsum illo magni vero quaerat quam ipsam iste autem quisquam, aperiam laudantium cumque, porro amet! Sint ipsa, laborum!</p>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ab officiis nostrum modi aliquam, rem dicta deleniti provident sunt, libero nobis ea adipisci praesentium dolore fuga nesciunt iure at maiores!</p>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hyzzpbxr/).

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`[Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`Element.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches).
- [Guide to JavaScript Regular Expressions (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
- [`Node.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).
- [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).
- [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).
- [`while (...)` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).

Comment: Very Nice I like it! Thx for ES6 reference